# QMediaPlayer::position() return zero

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I was trying to get position of current media like that:

```
player->setNotifyInterval(500);

connect(Player::player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, &Player::ChangedPosition);

void Player::ChangedPosition(qint64 position)
{
    Player::currentPosition = position; //qint64 variable
    //currentPosition still 0

    qDebug() << "current position: " << currentPosition;

    return;
}
```

I was trying to make like that (because doc of Qt **does not say about this slot** `QMediaPlayer::setPosition`)

```
connect(Player::player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, &QMediaPlayer::setPosition);
```

I have two class (`Playlist` and `Player`):

`playlistmanager` - object of `Playlist` class

`playermanager` - object of `Player` class

set playlist and play it:

```
//set current media
playlistmanager->GetCurrentPlayList()->setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
//play this media
playermanager->play();
//set current position
playermanager->SetPositionOfTrack(playermanager->GetPositionOfTrack());
```

After this code media is playing but from the beginning

Here two methods of `Player` class:

```
qint64 Player::GetPositionOfTrack()
{
    return currentPosition; //qint64 variable in class
}

void Player::SetPositionOfTrack(const qint64 position)
{
    player->setPosition(position);

    return;
}
```

So, How can I get **current position** of **current media**?

Comment: Can you show the minimal example to reproduce and also the source code?

Comment: Did you start the player (e.g. via [play()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#play))?

Comment: @Scheff Sure. Added code.

Comment: try replacing `playermanager->SetPositionOfTrack(playermanager->GetPositionOfTrack())` by `playermanager->SetPositionOfTrack(qint64(1000))` ?? it seems to me you are setting the position of the track to itself

Comment: @gui3 you are right. I'm saving position of media and setting it again. I need it but `currentPosition = 0`. How can I fix it?

Comment: what do you need it for ?

Comment: @gui3 After **update** playlist I load it. So If media **played** I need to **save position of this media** to **set it again** after update playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use `this` pointer if I create object like that: `player = new QMediaPlayer(this);`. Wrong example:

```
connect(Player::player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, &QMediaPlayer::setPosition);
```

Constructor of the correct class:

```
    Player::Player()
    {
        try
        {
            player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
        }
        catch(std::bad_alloc &exp)
        {
            #ifndef Q_DEBUG
            qCritical() << "Exception caught: " << exp.std::bad_alloc::what();
            #endif
            abort();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            #ifndef Q_DEBUG
            qCritical() << "Some exception caught";
            #endif
            abort();
        }
    
        player->setNotifyInterval(500);
        
        connect(this, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, &Player::ChangedPosition);
    
        return;
    }
```